# Drupal 6 Node Creation PHP Script with File upload not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, file, upload

I've got this PHP script I'm working on to import pay-stubs into Drupal. It's doing everything the way I want except the script is not attaching the uploaded PDF file to the node.

A few notes; Drupal's filesystem is set to private, not sure if this makes a difference or not. Second, the pdf files are already in the correct location 'paystubs/[uid]/paystub_1.pdf' so I think my problem is that the file is not being associated to the node correctly.

**Here is the code**

```
function create_drupal_node($employeeID, $employeeDate, $drupalUid, $file2) {
  $sourcePDF = "/var/www/html/mgldev.************.com/burst_pdfs/pdfs/" . $file2;
  $destinationPDF = '/paystubs/' . $drupalUid . '/' . $file2;
  $destination = '/paystubs/' . $drupalUid . '/';

  if (!file_check_directory($destination, TRUE)){
    echo "Failed to check dir, does it exist?";
    mkdir($destination);    
    echo "trying to drupal mkdir...";
  }

  // Copy the file to the Drupal files directory 
  if (file_exists($sourcePDF)) {
    if(!rename($sourcePDF, $destinationPDF)) {
        echo "Failed to move file\n";
    } 
  }

  //Create node and attach file uplaod
  $file_drupal_path = "paystubs/" . $drupalUid . "/" . $file2;
  $mime = 'pdf/application';

  $file = new stdClass();
  $file->filename = $file2;
  $file->filepath = $file_drupal_path;
  $file->filemime = $mime;
  $file->filesize = filesize($file_drupal_path);

  $file->uid = $drupalUid;
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  $file->timestamp = time();
  drupal_write_record('files', $file);

  $node = new StdClass();
  $node->type = 'paystub';
  $node->body = $employeeID;
  $node->title = $employeeDate;
  $node->field_paystub_upload = array(
    array(
      'fid' => $file->fid,
      'title' => $file2,
      'filename' => $file->filename,
      'filepath' => $file->filepath,
      'filesize' => $file->filesize,
      'mimetype' => $mime,
      'data' => array(
        'description' => $file2,
      ),
      'list' => 1,
    ),
  );
  $node->uid = $drupalUid;
  $node->status = 1;
  $node->active = 1;
  $node->promote = 1;
  node_save($node); 
}
```

The node is created and the title and body of the node have the right values. When I look at the node using Devel module I can see that the 'field_paystub_upload' array is null. So for some reason its doing everything right except attaching the file to the node and that is what I've been banging my head on for days. Best response gets on free internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal's *file.inc* [file_save_upload](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save_upload/6) uses `$_FILES`, which is a [global, magically set by PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). Drupal expects an uploaded file, not a file that exists locally.

You best just call a custom file-saver method, to process local files. Make sure its path up in the `files` database-table too. [file_save_upload](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save_upload/6) will be valuable for creating such a helper method.

Comment: gah, could you elaborate/get me started on calling file_save_upload. I was trying to call file_save_upload where the file gets renamed in the original code but its not working correctly.

Comment: Alright, I found this link, seems like it might be close to my solution but im still confused as to exactly how it should be inserted into my node save function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796948/how-can-i-associate-many-existing-files-with-drupal-filefield

Comment: Sorry, I re-read my answer after your question and see that I did not point out clear enought that **File_save_upload itself is unusable**, instead you should make your own my_file_save_upload(), which instead of using $_FILES, uses the file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to [berkes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73673/berkes) for helping me solve this problem. Turns out that since the files were already on the drupal webserver and not being uploaded to PHP $_FILES global variable, I was unable to programmatically upload the file correctly.

This was causing every other way I've tried to fail. I tried using Drupals defualt upload module and I also tried using CCK's fielfield module both were not working. Thanks to berkes suggestion I found a function that comes with CCK's filefield widget to save uploaded files that are already on the server. Hopefully this helps someone else.

[This is the function](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/field_file_save_file/6) I found that can save a file thats already on the web-server.

Here is the working code I used to create the node and attach the file after calling field_file_save_file.

```
function create_drupal_node($employeeID, $employeeDate, $drupalUid, $file2){
    $file_remove_html_extention = substr($file2, 0, -7);
    $file_pdf = $file_remove_html_extention . '.pdf';
```

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'paystub';
$node->status = 1;
$node->uid = $drupalUid;
$node->title = $employeeDate . ' - eStub';
$node->body = $employeeID;
$node->created = time();
$node->changed = $node->created;
$node->promote = 1;
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->format = 1;
$node->language = 'en';

$file = '/var/www/html/mgldev.foobar.com/burst_pdfs/pdfs/' . $file_pdf;

// Get the path to your Drupal site's files directory 
$dest_folder = '/paystubs/' . $drupalUid;
$dest = 'paystubs/' . $drupalUid . '/' . $file_pdf;

if (!file_check_directory($dest_folder, TRUE)){
mkdir($dest_folder);
```

}

// Load the CCK field
$field = content_fields('field_paystub_upload', 'paystub');
// Load the appropriate validators
$validators = array_merge(filefield_widget_upload_validators($field));
// Create the file object
$file = field_file_save_file($file, $validators, $dest_folder);
// Apply the file to the field, this sets the first file only, could be looped
// if there were more files
$node->field_paystub_upload = array(0 => $file);
// The file has been copied in the appropriate directory, so it can be
// removed from the import directory
unlink($file);


// change file status to permanent
file_set_status($file,1);   
node_save($node);


    }
</pre></code>

Thanks again berkes

Comment: Hi hus- can i just ask how you are invoking the function? have you created a module to deal with this or is this a custom script that calls the Drupal Bootstrap at some point? (I am trying to do something similar and it would be useful to find out)